# PHP: session expiring automatically on some servers

Tags: php

I have a website built using PHP. My website consists of some Education Material/Documents which users can get only when they pay for it through clickbank. On the backend, their payment status will change from "Unpaid" to "paid".

But when I test it by paying on clickbank website and redirecting back to my website, the session is automatically expiring. It is working fine on my system but not on client's system.

Please tell me what kind of issue is this? I will explain more if there is any further query.

Comment: Maybe you are jumping from http to https, or other way around. This loses session at times if i remember correctly.

Comment: Yes i am jumping from http:// to https:// and redirecting bak to http://. SO what is the solution for that?

Comment: Should i set the user id in Cookie then? I know this is not a correct way to do, so please help me what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate using the ClickBank API to do the processing, which keeps the user on your site instead of redirecting them to the ClickBank API and destroying your session.

https://sandbox.clickbank.com/api_12_examples/api_example.php

This would return a success/fail code which you could then use in your decision to mark the order as paid or unpaid.

Comment: First of all bundle of thanks for your reply. But how could user pay then? For payment and to enter other relevant information (e.g: credit card number), user should be redirect to clickbank site.